# Debug dll file used in python script IDA

Tags: ida, dll, python

I am fairly new to RE on windows.
I have a python script which via ctypes uses functions from a dll.

I don't know if it's possible, but I would like to debug the dll used in the python script (the dll is not executable).

I tried to attach to the python process, but it exits right after, and I also tried to start the process from IDA, but I get a python console and my breackpoint is never reached.

So how can I do it?

Comment: One of the ways could be - In windbg use `sxe ld <dll>` to stop when the dll is loaded into the process and set breakpoints on the exported functions. Try to have debug symbols for python and the dll you're targeting.

Comment: @sudhackar Hi! Thanks for your comment! How can I use windbg to do that ? (I never use it before ^^')